# How do I reduce scope of mutable

Tags: rust, immutability, borrowing

I have a vector of elements which I traverse and check for some property (immutable). In some cases I would then perform a mutable operation on a single item in that vector followed by an update of the container. How would I do that?

```
struct A {
    buffer: Vec<B>,
}

impl A {
    fn update(&self) {}
}

struct B {}

impl B {
    fn check(&self) -> bool { true }
    fn do_stuff(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { buffer: vec![B{}] };

    for b in a.buffer.iter_mut() { // mutable borrow occurs here
        if b.check() {
            b.do_stuff();
            a.update();  // imutable borrow occurs here
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if I go for an immutable `iter()`. Is there a possibility to turn it mutable for the scope of `do_stuff`?

Comment: Is the update method acting on `buffer` or on some other fields?

Comment: IMO, the easiest way, by far, is to iterate the container by index. Not so pretty, but it works.

Comment: @rolisz. imutalbe on buffer

Comment: @rodrigo. Yes you are correct. I was looking for something more rustonic though. Let's see

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that depending on your usecase, the compiler might actually prevent you from having a bug. Whether this is a case of 'the borrow checker getting in the way' or 'the borrow checker saving you from a bug' very much depends on what you actually are planning to do in the `update` method.

With its current signature this method is allowed to perform any number of operations on the `Vec` which might trigger its reallocation. Or even exchange the entire `Vec` for a different one. Both would be sure to invalidate your iterator over the buffer.

It's applaudable, that you try to refrain from using indices. In case you have a logic error here all you would do is to trade a compile time error for a runtime error (maybe an out of bound access), which is arguably harder to find or debug.